# Horizontal spacing in inline lists

Tags: enumitem

I'm using the `enumitem` package and want to have very compact list:

- left aligned without margin
- minimal vertical and horizontal spacing

In the code below, this is what I try to achieve with

```
\setlist{align=left,noitemsep,nosep,left=0pt}
```

However, I also want to use the inline lists, but now they have a lot of horizontal spacing:

[image: compact vertical lists]

For completeness, without the custom list settings, you get:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\RequirePackage[inline]{enumitem}
\setlist{align=left,noitemsep,nosep,left=0pt} % to make lists more compact
\begin{document}
    \noindent
    Inline list:
    \begin{enumerate*}
        \item test
        \item test
    \end{enumerate*}
    
    \noindent
    Normal list:
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item test
        \item test
    \end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

From the `enumitem` documentation, it seems that you cannot alter the settings of the starred versions independently and you have to define a new list using `\newlist`.
However, I was not able to get this to work.

1. **Is there a way to make compact lists without altering the spacing in inline list?**
2. **If 1. cannot be done, how do you define your own inline list?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `align=left` seems to be affecting the inline counterpart. Even if you make settings specifically to `enumerate` inline lists still does have the side effect

```
\setlist[enumerate]{align=left,noitemsep,nosep,left=0pt}
```

One workaround could be to create a custom list with the specific formatting

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[inline]{enumitem}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\newlist{xenumerate}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[xenumerate]{align=left,nosep,left=0pt,label=\arabic*.}


\begin{document}
\noindent
Inline list:
\begin{enumerate*}
\item test
\item test
\end{enumerate*}

\Blindlist{xenumerate}[10]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

The option `align=left` causes the unnecessary space for inline lists. But you don't need it for your wanted output. The results are the same, at least in my test. Just delete the option and it seems to work, even with nested lists of different types:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[inline]{enumitem}
\setlist{noitemsep,nosep,left=0pt} % to make lists more compact
\begin{document}
    \noindent
    Inline list:
    \begin{enumerate*}
        \item test
        \item test
    \end{enumerate*}
    
    \noindent
    Normal list:
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item test
        \item test
    \end{enumerate}

    \begin{itemize}
        \item An 
        \begin{description}
            \item[test] item 
        \end{description}
        \item item
    \end{itemize}

    \begin{description}
        \item[test] item
        \item[second] test 
    \end{description}
\end{document}}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! It was indeed `align=left` option that caused the problem, but simply deleting it yields different results (in general), e.g. double digit labels will align to the right.

Comment: Ok, that may be a problem. I only tested it with your example and some simple `itemize` and `description` lists. But now you got an answer with a new environment.

Comment: Just tested it. But with leftaligned labels you'll get an horizontal indention of the following text when a numbered list switches from single to double digits. Doesn't that look a little bit awkward with regard to formatting? Of course, only my personal opinion, no offense ;)